# Could not include namespace System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am unable to include System.Threading.Tasks in my project.

I am Using Asp.net 2013 (4.5)

I am getting the following error -

> The type or namespace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I had refered earlier questions and they suggested in 4.0+ versions of ASP.NET it will work fine but I coudnt include it in my project.

Help me thanks.

Comment: Did you add it as a reference to your project (as the error asks)?

Comment: How to add it I dont know much about c#. I am new to this.

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` is in mscorlib - if you haven't even got that, I strongly suspect your project is *not* targeting .NET 4.5. Look in your project properties.

Comment: Ya John I have .NET 4.5 in my machine but my project is targeting 2.0 thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Threading.Tasks.Task` is in `mscorlib` which in `.NET4.5`. My project is not targeting, so in project properties need to change the target to `4.5`.